# NoxPlayer Android Emulator sometimes opens Google Play Store but sometimes the only option is a game store

Tags: noxplayer

NoxPlayer Android Emulator sometimes opens Google Play Store but sometimes the only option is a game store.

For example, a lot of the time I get this appeared.

[image]

The options like the little Google Play icon at the top of this window or the search bar aren't bringing up the actual Google Play Store.

[image]

From time to time, the Google Play Store has come up, but I'm not sure what I've clicked to bring it up.

How can I ensure it opens the actual Google Play Store, not the games store?

Answer (score 3):

looks to me like you have to double click the nox assist icon on the desktop, rather than the nox icon , that will open up a different executable.. and the google play there is normal

[image]

NoxAsst is a shortcut to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin\MultiPlayerManager.exe" -shortCut`

Nox is a shortcut to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Nox\bin\Nox.exe"`

By clicking NoxAssist, then you get the NoxAsst window

[image]

And the google play icon there (in the NoxAsst window) works